# Creating a model for Garrys mod. How can I copy/paste my model in the edit mode to create a phys model?

Tags: modeling, export

I'm following this youtube tutorial but the teacher copy/pasted and continued on like nothing. I've looked around and I guess theres shift-d to duplicate but I'm really just trying to make a copy of this model to rename it with _phys at the end.

Here's the tutorial and its time stamped at the part I'm stuck at.
https://youtu.be/LWvAkJryAhI?t=180

Answer (score 1):

one way is (the tutorial one):

- select the object (be sure you are in "object mode" and not in "edit mode")
- control c to copy
- control v to paste
- g (move), x (move only on X axis - so you can position better your object), move the mouse, left click when you want to drop the copied object

the other is:

- select the object you need to copy (be sure you are in "object mode" and not in "edit mode")
- shift d (duplicate)
- x (move only on X axis - so you can position better your object)
- left click to position the object

otherwise you can do your copy stuff directly inside "scene collection" 
right click, copy, bla bla - see gif -->

[image]